# Convert Active Support timezone original format into a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I'm trying to convert Active Support timezone original format into a string. I want to store it in an array of characters then parse each needed data individually.

```
Time.zone = current_user.timezone
date_and_time = Time.zone.now
```

Now

```
date_and_time  = Thu, 21 Apr 2016 20:58:04 PDT -07:00
```

Ruby method ( to_s ) does not convert it. I found other ways to convert it to  but all of them will change the format to numbers only, I want the day to stay the same because I will store it in a variable then use it in a different method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
date_and_time.strftime("%a %d %b %Y")
```

Also You can check this [guide](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime), to get format you want

Comment: Thanks this is exactly how I want it just added the hours and minutes and looks great ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.to_formatted_s(DATE_FORMAT)` for this.

```
time = Time.now                    # => Thu Jan 18 06:10:17 CST 2007

time.to_formatted_s(:db)           # => "2007-01-18 06:10:17"
time.to_formatted_s(:long)         # => "January 18, 2007 06:10"
time.to_formatted_s(:long_ordinal) # => "January 18th, 2007 06:10"
time.to_formatted_s(:rfc822)       # => "Thu, 18 Jan 2007 06:10:17 -0600"
time.to_formatted_s(:iso8601)      # => "2007-01-18T06:10:17-06:00"
```

A list of all DATE_FORMATS and more information can be found here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-to_formatted_s

Answer (score 1):

You should get what you want using this :

```
date_and_time.strftime("%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S UTC %:z")
```

Please see [strftime Docs](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) for more info

**Explanation**

Reason for hardcoding UTC is so that according to the docs

`%z - Time zone as hour and minute offset from UTC`

So i believe it should be UTC all the time.

Comment: @PetrGazarov I've added an explanation for doing that. But if you still think it's a bad idea could you please point me to any docs or reference for the same. Thanks